# Parsing a C string from an AT Command

Tags: c

I'm executing the following command:  **AT+QFOTADL="https://www.quectel.com:100/update.zip"**

and I get the following response:

```
OK
+QIND: "FOTA","HTTPSTART"
+QIND: "FOTA","HTTPEND",0 //Finish downloading the package from HTTPS server.
+QIND: "FOTA","START"
+QIND: "FOTA","UPDATING", 1%
+QIND: "FOTA","UPDATING", 2%
...
+QIND: "FOTA","UPDATING", 100%
+QIND: "FOTA","RESTORE", 1%
+QIND: "FOTA","RESTORE", 2%
+QIND: "FOTA","RESTORE", 100%
+QIND: "FOTA","END",0 //Finish upgrading the firmware.
```

and I would like to check if the firmware has been upgraded.

so I would like to parse the the last entry where I get "End",0

so I suppose there is a string output that I will get

and I Will write

```
while(parseString() !="End,0")
{

continue read the string
}
```

but I don't know how would I get the following **"End", 0**

The problem is the result is continous so I'm not sure how to process it until I get End,0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Read single characters and buffer then into a `line`.
- Assuming lines are separated by the classic CR,LF combination (`"\r\n"`), wait until the incoming character is a line-feed (`'\n'`), since that signifies the end of a line.
- Analyze the line, to see if it contains the significant text, i.e. if `strstr(line, "\"FOTA\",\"END\",0")` is non-`NULL`.

That should get you along the way. There will be some brittleness that can be improved by more advanced code, i.e. the above `strstr()` will fail if there is an extra space in the output but that might be OK. You should also of course have limits in place for `line` length to protect against buffer overflow, a time-out is often handy, and so on.

Here's an attempt at pseudo-coding it:

```
bool wait_update(void)
{
  char line[128] = "";
  size_t pos = 0;

  for (;;)
  {
    const int ch = get_next_character();
    if (ch == EOF)  // Time-out or I/O failure, perhaps?
      return false;

    if (ch == '\n')
    {
      if (strstr(line, "\"FOTA\",\"END\",0") != NULL)
        return true;
      pos = 0; // Drop line, wait for another.
    }
    else
    {
      if (pos < (sizeof line) - 1)  // Avoid overflow.
      {
        line[pos++] = (char) ch;
      }
    }
    line[pos] = '\0';  // Keep line properly terminated.
  }
}
```

The above is (as should be obvious, hopefully) 100% untested.

Comment: Thanks, Can you show a sample code please, even a pseudo code would be sufficient